# tar compress with -C argument doesn't work

Tags: compression, ubuntu-16.04, tar

This set of commands aren't working as they're supposed to:

```
mkdir -p /home/git/root_backup_folder
cd /home/git/gitlab/git-data/repositories
tar zcvf dailybackup.tar.gz * -C /home/git/root_backup_folder
```

It is completely ignoring the -C argument and creating the file in /home/git/gitlab/git-data/repositories. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to achieve the behaviour of the following command: `tar zcvf  /home/git/root_backup_folder/dailybackup.tar.gz *`?

Comment: Yes, but I thought -C argument was also for that. I'm seeing now it is only to extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -C flag doesn't specify the output directory. You need to do this at the point at which you specify the archive file. So, your command could become:

```
tar zcvf /home/git/root_backup_folder/dailybackup.tar.gz *
```

Comment: I thought -C was also to specify a target folder to compress, turns out it is only for extraction. So your way is the only way.

Comment: Thanks, @p4x, depending on the OS/distro -C will do slightly different things on creation as well as extraction, I think. Feel free to accept the answer!